# Откуда хостеры берут IP адреса

Tags: ip

Откуда хостинг компании берут ip адреса, предположим есть небольшая хостинг компания и ей нужен небольшой блок ip адресов, где она их возьмет? Я знаю что сами ip адреса берутся из Интернет-регистратуры (LIR). Что получается хостинг компании закупают адреса у самих LIR, или у местного провайдера можно закупить, а местные провайдеры в свою очередь уже закупают адреса напрямую у LIR или как это происходит?

Comment: По всякому бывает

Comment: Если хостер получил автономную систему, то может покупать сам у LIR или, если он большой, попробовать сам стать LIR'ом. Если автономной системы или BGP-сессий с провайдерами нет, то он может взять IP только у своего провайдера. Но учитывая, что IP-адреса (v4) уже года 2 как полностью закончились, на первое место встает вопрос найти того, у кого они еще есть и кто готов предложить, а дальше действовать по обстоятельствам

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все понятно, а чего вы это в ответ не написали, я бы плюсанул

Answer (score 1):

Если хостер получил автономную систему, то может покупать сам у LIR или, если он большой, попробовать сам стать LIR'ом.

Если автономной системы или BGP-сессий с провайдерами нет, то он может взять IP только у своего провайдера. Но учитывая, что IP-адреса (v4) уже года 2 как полностью закончились, на первое место встает вопрос найти того, у кого они еще есть и кто готов предложить, а дальше действовать по обстоятельствам.

---

Спасибо [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762550/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82-ip-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0#comment1183371_762550) за полезный комментарий.